# VB.NET sharing information between two datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two `DataGridViews`, `DataGridView1` is holding information from database, once a user click on an item in the `DataGridView1` is should be sent to the `DataGridView2`, my question is how to specify which information is needed from `DataGridView1`.

for example `DataGridView1` holds thees information :

```
           - ItemName
           - ItemDescription
           - ItemPrice
```

in `DataGridView2` it has these columns

```
           - Qty (Quantity that is inserted by user)
           - ItemName
           - ItemPrice
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, please edit your question to explain what you've tried.

Comment: Why not use just one datagridview, to avoid repeating information?

Answer (score 0):

To get the data from the clicked cell/row you can use the cellClick- or rowEnter-event. This example code adds the values 'name' and 'description' from the clicked DGV1-row to the first DGV2-row:

```
Private Sub DGV1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV1.CellContentClick
    DGV2.rows(e.RowIndex).cells(0).value = DGV2.rows(0).cells(1).value 'itemName
    DGV2.rows(e.RowIndex).cells(2).value = DGV2.rows(0).cells(2).value 'itemDescription
End Sub
```

If you want to constantly add a new row to DGV2 you can use the .rowCount-method of the DGV instead of an specific index for the row.